# Chrome dev tools keeps stopping at ` if (!invalidParentOrAncestor) { return; }` in react-dom.development.js

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

Every time I refresh the page with dev tools open it stops at a break point (that I didn't set and every time I unset it, it comes back to life on refresh) at some code:

```
if (!invalidParentOrAncestor) {
  return;
}
```

In some file I didn't write. I don't know if this has to do with `webpack` and its devtools configuration. It just started happening (no idea why) and is very annoying.

What is this?

Answer (score 0):

Might be one possibility: Make sure the option `Pause on exceptions` is not enabled in `Dev Tools`

Disabled

[image: Pause on Exceptions Disabled]

enabled

[image: Pause on Exceptions Enabled]

(There is also a `Pause on caught exceptions` option there to play with)

It might be the case that it is some exception and dev tools is forcing you to break if open.